# Unable to Project MacBook Pro Screen to Old iMac

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, hdmi, target-display

I have a new MacBook Pro which I am not able to connect to my old iMac so I can use iMac as my secondary monitor.

Details of MacBook and iMac
MacBook Pro:  13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports
iMac: 21.5 inch Mid 2011

Here is what I did but that didn't work:

1. Put a Thunderbolt cord into iMac and attached it to a Thunderbolt to HDMI Adapter
2. Connected a new HDMI cord to the adapter (from iMac) to the MacBook Pro adapter
3. Pressed Command + F2 on iMAC
4. Nothing happened

Please help.

Comment: You need to connect the Thunderbolt ports directly - not go through HDMI adapters

Comment: Thanks Allan. Are you suggesting that I should put a Thunderbolt Cable into my 2011 iMAC and then get an adapter from Thunderbolt to USB C to connect to Macbook Pro?

Comment: That's exactly how!  You just need a TB 2 cable and the TB 3 to TB 2 adapter.  That will make it work.